# Migrate from increments to bigIncrements from existing table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Im been searching around in laravel issues/forums on how to migrate changes from `increments()` to `bigIncrements()` using existing tables.

Error :  `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1833 Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key constraint 'account_users_acc_id_foreign' of table 'mydatabasename.account_users' (SQL: ALTER TABLE accounts CHANGE id id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL)`

i know its because of the foreign table, then i tried to disabled constraint using `Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints()`

Error : `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of './mydatabasename/#sql-ea_201' to './mydatabasename/accounts' (errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed) (SQL: ALTER TABLE accounts CHANGE id id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL)`

in my `up()` function:

[image]

i also tried to switch the order of the loops

Error: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1832 Cannot change column 'acc_id': used in a foreign key constraint 'account_users_acc_id_foreign' (SQL: ALTER TABLE account_users CHANGE acc_id acc_id BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE app_user_id app_user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, CHANGE approved_by approved_by BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE rejected_by rejected_by BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL)`

Is there any way to solve this?

References:

DBAL doctrine : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/schema-manager.html

Comment: might be silly but have you tried switching the order of for loops?

Comment: yup. i tried. still the same. i edited the error in post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to implement like @brice suggested. for now its working..

below is migration code. i dont know it is the best practice or not

this is my gist : https://gist.github.com/afiqiqmal/6518a2048246cd76c03bdee04ff87a82

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Could you:

1. Store each table's foreign keys in an array of `[$table_name => $array_of_foreign_keys]`
2. Drop all foreign keys
3. Change each table's `id` column to use `bigIncrements`
4. Change each foreign key column to be type `unsigned big integer`
5. Loop through the array from step 1, recreating all foreign keys (by looping through each foreign key by table name)